# Possible to receive only with Arduino Serial?

Tags: arduino

Is it possible to run a serial port (soft or hardware) that only reads? The examples I see all involve two pins for read and write. I would like to use the TX pin for something else.

Comment: Will try just removing TX code from the SoftwareSerial library here: https://github.com/jbeuckm/SoftwareSerialIn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version of the SoftwareSerial library with the TX parts gone:

https://github.com/jbeuckm/SoftwareSerialIn